# Due to Multi-geo is there any changes in the CSOM data or API call?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, csom, multi-geo

Consider if a Tenant is enabled Multi-Geo, using CSOM will cause any changes in the returned data? Any modification is required for CSOM API?